# Run Python as windows a service - call another python scrip with modules

Tags: python, windows, service, call

Im trying to run python as windows service.

The following this post is working okay: https://gist.github.com/guillaumevincent/d8d94a0a44a7ec13def7f96bfb713d3f

But when I try to import some of my other python and call from this service it wont work.

code of service :

```
    import servicemanager
import socket
import sys
import win32event
import win32service
import win32serviceutil

import datetime

# impoort own module
from modules import copy_log



class TestService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "TestService7"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test Service7"



    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)


    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        rc = None
        while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            with open('C:\\test\\TestService.log', 'a') as f:

                self.count = self.count + 1
                f.write(str(self.count) + ' :: '+str(now) + '\n')
                f.write('________________\n')
                f.write('test service running...\n')
                #call own module
                "Here is simple function im my seprare python project and is not working"
                copy_log.CopyTest()

            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 1000*10)


    def main(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(TestService)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(TestService)
```

example of file/module that is called by python service:

```
import datetime
from shutil import copyfile

class CopyTest(object):


    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__str__())
        pass

    def copy_it(self):
        copyfile("C://test_read/aaa.txt",
                 "C:///test_write/aaa.txt")
```

and is not working that. I don't know why?

Comment: This looks like an interesting question, but I don't fully understand what you are asking. Can you please try to add your code and where you're getting stuck, including any error messages -- all to your question (just click edit), not as a comment.  Make sure any code is formatted (select the code and type control-K)

Comment: I added Can You check please?

Comment: The code should be added to the original question, don't post part of your question as an answer. give it another go!

Comment: I removed. Can someone take a look on that? thank You

Comment: Excellent! Now you'll have a better shot at attracting a good answer to your question.